# Add correlation coefficient to seaborn PairGrid with sparse data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

I'm attempting to put together a PairGrid demonstrating correlations between values for various groups. However, I'm running into an issue with calculating the correlation coefficients because the data are sparse, with only some groups having entries for all values (see example df below).

```py
group,PMTS049_X1,PMTS049_X2,PMTS049_X3,PMTS050_X1,PMTS050_X2,PMTS050_X3,PMTS051_X1,PMTS051_X2,PMTS051_X3
A-1155463_0.0045724735 uM,,,,,,,1.04971460376213,1.179179562152282,1.108186227034926
A-1155463_0.0137174204 uM,,,,,,,0.8988914257248843,1.1081975403870097,1.1212163392527827
A-1155463_0.0411522626 uM,,,,,,,0.7568287138412346,1.3430358264779123,0.6976356991070309
A-1155463_0.1234567894 uM,,,,,,,0.8722751660077679,1.2813232679016255,0.7168068340749701
A-1155463_0.3703703698 uM,,,,,,,1.0048500564303646,0.9822764937914188,0.7848035710436727
A-1155463_1.1111111109 uM,,,,,,,0.714489988829366,1.0212592818965238,0.9073404868051366
A-1155463_10.0 uM,,,,,,,0.8653477680327408,1.0148035026211837,1.078068956627115
A-1155463_3.3333333328 uM,,,,,,,0.7886497200478821,1.2509355686549108,1.102089542546691
AR00536370_0.004572474 uM,0.904860165175536,0.630159462892308,0.9489118135217488,,,,,,
AR00536370_0.013717421 uM,1.0775483229823892,1.0225981211028854,0.882809722682908,,,,,,
AR00536370_0.041152263 uM,0.651388505631196,0.6464619116451127,0.9482309449208448,,,,,,
AR00536370_0.12345679 uM,1.1258840716614356,1.086943922239876,0.9390622801310888,,,,,,
AR00536370_0.37037037 uM,0.8376593712267018,0.6137443429066174,1.1138346723430423,,,,,,
AR00536370_1.111111111 uM,0.889524913610136,0.614134774405636,1.024540177391546,,,,,,
AR00536370_10.0 uM,1.1265016447481484,1.0079550835923723,1.020468601391634,,,,,,
AR00536370_3.333333333 uM,0.7712691128712621,0.5893153808880822,0.9392664499480852,,,,,,
AZ-628_0.0045724738 uM,0.9076622425465212,1.0934450174529409,0.8998208357308275,0.5434529688654449,1.0562636134080905,0.7715563402897756,0.8276719202512567,1.186335347522918,0.8472096021168107
AZ-628_0.0137174214 uM,1.0963705071916314,0.7842348321294206,0.8315757098390226,1.1030070502236278,0.9908839527491846,0.6890801893628911,1.0576768873554188,0.6458275700418388,0.6252105837953932
AZ-628_0.0411522642 uM,0.4638659293322327,0.448229525781371,0.7834117035243882,0.6719774212414784,0.7929078280555364,0.5459489088307414,0.5319067062568421,0.7597553877201356,0.7555114458518108
AZ-628_0.1234567905 uM,0.7477873760694489,0.6876014256016453,0.7062173803657827,0.638953551272889,0.7319274702673808,0.5026056304516787,0.670610155828824,0.7502067504385757,0.728226016276163
AZ-628_0.3703703714 uM,0.6866247604514487,0.6283063570534719,0.4496522225873166,0.6832591578588455,0.5954091111794844,0.3100417445307057,0.6715651569282897,0.618884745101185,0.3682229011490131
AZ-628_1.1111111121 uM,0.5067878800206379,0.4427746455438304,0.3437829115127019,0.5443902391591303,0.4502681586077313,0.4061182601803592,0.5963543157154589,0.54950245634917,0.2611084549558647

# copy the data to the clipboard and use
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

So far, what I have come up with is the following:

```
def corr_func(x, y, **kws):
    r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("{:.2f}".format(r),
            xy=(.3, .45), xycoords=ax.transAxes, size=30)

def plot_corrplot(df):
    g = sns.PairGrid(df, diag_sharey=False, corner=False)
    g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, s=10, color='black')
    g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, color='grey')
    g.map_upper(corr_func)
    plt.show()
```

The scatterplots and kde plots display as I would expect, however, I can't properly calculate the correlations due to the presence of NaNs:

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Essentially, what I need to do is calculate the coefficient while ignoring any unplotted entries (NaNs).

An example plot is shown below, generated without mapping the corr_function. In this case, the pearson coefficients should be in the upper plots.

[image: incomplete_plot]

Comment: You likely have to change `corr_func` to remove `NaN`s from `x` and `y` before passing them to `stats.pearsonr`. Or if you want to skip over plots where `NaN`s are present use `np.isnan(x).any()` to check for them.

Comment: To mask `x` and `y` properly you'd use `xnan = np.isnan(x); ynan = np.isnan(y)` then combine them with `nans = xnan | ynan` and then get your correlation with `stats.pearsonr(x[~nans], y[~nans])`.